# Add custom splash screen image in Yocto (the best way)

Tags: splash-screen, yocto

I successfully changed the splash screen image on my embedded system, Toradex iMX6. I changed the kernel defconfig found in the sub-directory to the kernel *.bb file and added my image (logo_custom_clut224.ppm) to my pre-build kernel directory ./tmp-glibc/work-shared/colibri-imx6/kernel-source/drivers/video/logo/ and then re-compiled the kernel.

Is it possible to do this nicer? I would really like to change the step where I manually copy my image to the pre-build directory. Can I somehow change the *.bb file to include my image and use it as my custom splash image?

Or is it possible to do my own recipe that changes the defconfig file and includes my image in any way before the kernel is build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never got the Splash functionality to work. But I found a solution to change the static startup logo for both u-boot and kernel.

**Create boot images**

I created a script that converted a jpg image to the two different images that is needed for u-boot and kernel.

```
#!/bin/bash
IMAGE_JPG_INPUT=<YOUR_IMAGE_NAME>.jpg
IMAGE_UBOOT=toradex.bmp
IMAGE_KERNEL=logo_custom_clut224.ppm
echo "Converting $IMAGE_JPG_INPUT" 
jpegtopnm $IMAGE_JPG_INPUT | ppmquant 224 > tmp.ppm
pnmnoraw tmp.ppm > $IMAGE_KERNEL
echo ">> Kernel image created: $IMAGE_KERNEL" 
ppmtobmp -bpp 8 tmp.ppm > $IMAGE_UBOOT
echo ">> U-boot image created: $IMAGE_UBOOT" 
rm tmp.ppm
```

**U-boot logo**

The solution is to replace the default boot image (toradex.bmp in my case) in `u-boot/tools/logos`. I created a bbappend file, u-boot-toradex_2016.11.bbappend, in `<MY_CUSTOM_LAYER>/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-toradex/`.

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += "file://toradex.bmp"

do_unpack_append() {
    os.system("cp ${PWD}/toradex.bmp ${PWD}/git/tools/logos/")
}
```

The copy operation needs to be done in this function, because when you reach do_patch_prepend() the location of additional files is different if you run bitbake directly or working with devtool (then files are moved to `sources/u-boot-toradex/oe-local-files/`).

According to the recipe I added the boot image to `<MY_CUSTOM_LAYER>/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-toradex/u-boot-toradex`

**Kernel logo**

For the kernel logo the solution is similar. I created a bbappend file, linux-toradex_4.1-2.0.x.bbappend, in `<MY_CUSTOM_LAYER>/recipes-kernel/linux`

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x:"

SRC_URI += "file://logo_custom_clut224.ppm \
            file://enable-custom-logo \
            "

do_unpack_append() {
    os.system("cp ${PWD}/logo_custom_clut224.ppm ${PWD}/git/drivers/video/logo/")
    os.system("patch -s < enable-custom-logo")
}
```

Boot image is added to `<MY_CUSTOM_LAYER>/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x`. I also added a patch to enable custom logo to the kernel config file and also disabled the other logo image options. In my case there was a default defconfig file from the original recipe in the $PWD directory that I had to patch.

```
CONFIG_LOGO=y
+# CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_MONO is not set
+# CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_VGA16 is not set
+# CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_CLUT224 is not set
+CONFIG_LOGO_CUSTOM_CLUT224=y
```

U-boot and kernel was then updated on the target.

Answer (score 5):

I think here [psplash_git.bbappend](https://github.com/Guacamayo/meta-guacamayo/blob/master/meta-guacamayo/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend) is a good example of usage psplash in Yocto.

Comment: can you show how to actually use the `bbappend` file in a custom yocto project?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you can keep your changes as a patch and you can give it as a patch to yocto then, yocto can apply the patch the kernel if  you clean everything. This way is the most common way in the embedded linux systems which does not use Yocto system.

In yocto, I prefer to use psplash. It is easy to use and you can add a loader icon with the image. You just need to add psplash to your image and in the your psplash recipe you just need to give the image location to **`SPLASH_IMAGES`** definition.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to build our own recipe or layer to  easly customize psplash image. I have managed to create a layer [meta-splash](https://github.com/hamzamac/meta-splash) that does that. You can refere to it to see how it you can do it. Alternatively you can bake the layer in your image as follows.

1. Clone [meta-splash](https://github.com/hamzamac/meta-splash) layer in your Poky project: `git clone https://github.com/hamzamac/meta-splash.git`
2. Replace the default `logo.png` image with your logo image with name `logo.png` (the name can be customized in `customize.bb`)
3. Bake your image